# How can I combine objects with the same ID in a Java ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I am working in a problem with a list in Java and need to merge info of two objects from it.

This is my code:

```java
Person person1 = new Person(1, 470, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new position(45, LocalDate.now()), new position(42, LocalDate.now()) )) );
Person person2 = new Person(1, 320, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new position(35, LocalDate.now()) )) );
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(person1);
list.add(person2);

for(Person person:list){
    int id= person.getId();;
    List<position> aux = new ArrayList<>();
    list.stream().forEach(x -> {
        if(x.getId()==id){
            aux.addAll( x.getPosition());
            
        }
    });
    person.setPosition(aux);
}
```

This is my resulting list:

```
[
person{id=1, contrac=470, position=[position{id=45, bd=2023-04-14}, position{id=42, bd=2023-04-14}, position{id=35, bd=2023-04-14}]}, 
person{id=1, contrac=320, position=[position{id=45, bd=2023-04-14}, position{id=42, bd=2023-04-14}, position{id=35, bd=2023-04-14}, position{id=35, bd=2023-04-14}]}
]
```

The end result is two objects, but I need there to be only one.  How can I get only one?

I tried to get only one an object by ID with the positions of all the objects with the same ID.

Comment: You should add prose to describe what you are trying to accomplish with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do that.

#### 1. Use a Map

```
Map<Integer, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Person person : list) {
    int id = person.getId();
    if (!map.containsKey(id)) {
        map.put(id, person);
    } else {
        Person existingPerson = map.get(id);
        List<position> positions = existingPerson.getPosition();
        positions.addAll(person.getPosition());
        existingPerson.setPosition(positions);
    }
}
List<Person> mergedList = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
System.out.println(mergedList);
```

#### 2. Use a **Stream** and `Collectors.groupingBy()`

```
List<Person> mergedList = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getId))
            .values().stream()
            .map(group -> {
                int id = group.get(0).getId();
                int contract = group.get(0).getContract();
                List<Position> positions = group.stream()
                        .flatMap(person -> person.getPositions().stream())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                return new Person(id, contract, positions);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(mergedList);
```